# Why does GMDH work better than a random forest?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, random-forest

I did a little experiment and saw that the `gmdh` algorithm works very well for these toy data, much better than `random forest`.

```
X <- matrix(data = c(rnorm(2000)), ncol = 5, nrow = 500)
colnames(X) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

Y <-  c(10 + X[, "a"] * X[, "e"]^3)

 par(mfrow=c(2,1),mar=c(2,2,2,2))
 matplot(X,t="l",lty=1, main="data")
 plot(Y,t="l",  main="target")


tr <- 1:450
ts <- 451:500


library(GMDHreg)
gmdh <- gmdh.gia(X = X[tr,], y = Y[tr], prune = 5, criteria = "PRESS")
gmdh_pred <- predict(gmdh, X)[,1]
lines(gmdh_pred ,col=4)


library(randomForest)
rf <- randomForest(Y[tr]~.,X[tr,],ntree=500)
rf_pred <- predict(rf,X)
lines(rf_pred ,col=2)






par(mfrow=c(1,1),mar=c(2,2,2,2))
plot(Y[ts],t="l",lwd=10,col="gray70")
lines(gmdh_pred[ts],col=4,lwd=2)
lines(rf_pred[ts],col=2,lwd=2)

legend(x = "topright",
       legend = c("original", "GMDH", "RandomForest"),
       col = c(8,4,2), lwd = 2)
```

[image]

I'm interested in:

1. Why does gmdh work better?
2. Is it possible to make random forest work better?
3. For which data is it better to use the first algorithm and for which the second?

Comment: The formatting of the code is inconsistent. Can you [fix it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/613009/edit), please? (But *** *** *** ***without*** *** *** ***  "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not many details are provided, here is a quick take for the three questions posed:

1. No single algorithm is ever guarantee to outperform another, if that was the case we would invalidate the whole "[No free lunch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization)" notion. That said, it appears that the data generating process (DGP) here is of polynomial form so unsurprisingly [Group method of data handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_method_of_data_handling) (GMDH) is competitive as it is in some sense a polynomial neural network.
2. In this case, we can increase `mtry` the number of variables randomly sampled as candidates at each split and more competitive results. Especially given that only 2 out of 5 variables are relevant and in many cases our candidate tree might contain only irrelevant variables that increased number of variables examined can be very helpful.
3. Again there is not universal answer here but as mentioned in point 1, if we have a good understanding for the DGP, a method that seems to align with that DGP is a good *first* choice.